# index range Error

Tags: python

i keep getting an error 'IndexError: list index out of range'

not sure what im doing wrong it works for a couple runs an error
the only thing i can think of is that the names i getting are too long for the variable

```
        mylist = [x +'.mp3' for x in re.findall(r'file=(.*?).mp3',the_webpage)]
    #Remove Duplicates
    if mylist:
        mylist.sort()
        last = mylist[-1]
        for i in range(len(mylist)-3, -1, -1):
            if last == mylist[i]:
                del mylist[i]
            else:
                last = mylist[i]
    print " "
    #takes the quotes out of the string
    #ti = titl1[0]
    n1 = titl1[0]
    n2 = song1[0]

    #sg = song1
    sname = "".join(tuple(n1 + "-" + n2 + ".mp3"))

    print sname
    url = mylist[0]
```

results

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "grub.py", line 59, in <module>
    url = mylist[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: It is probably worth testing that `mylist=list(set([x+'.mp3' for ...]))` is not significantly slower than your code. It would definitely be easier to understand and maintain. For that matter, why not just `mylist=list(set(re.findall(r'file=(.*?.mp3)', the_webpage)))`?

Answer (score 6):

Your `IndexError` suggests that `mylist` is empty which means that you possibly removed more elements than you wanted to in your loop (or your list was empty to begin with).  To sort and remove duplicates, you can just do

```
mylist = sorted(set(mylist))
```

Even with this, it's not guaranteed that you won't get an empty list (if your list started out empty, it won't magically get more elements).  You can also make sure your list isn't empty before trying to assign `url`:

```
#"Look Before You Leap"  (LBYL)
if mylist:  
   url = mylist[0]
else:
   url = '???'
```

however, some (most) would consider a `try`-`except` clause more "pythonic" here ...

```
#Maybe it's "Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission" ... (EAFP)
try:
   url = mylist[0]
except IndexError:
   url = '???'
```

Comment: @Lenna -- You mean +1 for being lazy and not spending the time to figure out what the OP's code is actually doing ;-)

Answer (score 0):

what this means in general is that `mylist` does not have an index 0, which might imply that it's not actually a list like you think it is. you have an `if mylist` conditional, which suggests that maybe there are some cases in which mylist will be undefined. maybe this is one of those cases?

Comment: well im grabing all the MP3 links out of the webpage and passing them into a list which im not sure what other easier way